# Customize the lock error message with a variable of devise config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using devise as login framework, I tried to add the lock time in the lock error message of the file devise.en.yml, as below:

```
locked: "Your account is locked for %{config.unlock_in} minutes."
```

but the message does not change and the variable is not replaced by its value.

How can I do this, please ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have devise.rb file inside initializers?

Comment: Yes, I have. And this variable is will assigned. (The locking is working well. Only I need to add in the lock error message, how long will locked the user. Any idea ?

Comment: is it not interpolating config.unlock_in or is it not using your custom message at all?

Comment: I expected the message should have been "Your account is locked for 10 minutes." but the message is "Your account is locked for %{config.unlock_in} minutes." .

Answer (score 0):

I've customized the method def i18n_message of the class Devise::FailureApp and it is working for me.
The idea is to do the same way that was done for the variable %{authentication_keys} inside this method.So, add the variable unlock_in as below:

```
options[:unlock_in] = scope_class.unlock_in
```